# Vuejs create dynamically a Nav List Item from Route Children Paths

Tags: vue.js, quarkus, quasar-framework

I try to use to generate a dynamic nav list from my routes in my `routes.js`:

```js
    const routes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
        children: [
          { path: '', name: 'home', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') },
          { path: '/users', name: 'users', component: () => import('pages/Users.vue') },
          { path: '/news', name: 'news', component: () => import('pages/News.vue') },
        ],
      },
    
      // Always leave this as last one,
      // but you can also remove it
      {
        path: '*',
        component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue'),
      },
    ];
    
    export default routes;
```

that's the part of my MainLayout for the navigation list:

```html
      <ul>
        <li v-for="item in routes" :key="item">
          <router-link :to="item.path">{{item.name}}</router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

But I can't get a list and I'm getting no error, did I maybe use the global `MainLayout.vue` wrong here which contains my header and footer and other global stuff or how can I get all the paths from just one children?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
computed: {
    routeList() {
        return this.$router.options.routes
    }
}
```

Comment: hi and thank you, this works but I only get the route for the first route / but I need only the childrens like users and news.

Comment: Try to console.log(routeList). It will return an array with all routes, in your case 1 route with path: '/'. 

The following should work for you. 
this.$router.options.routes[0].children

Comment: thanks but I rewrote my layout now it works, maybe not the best but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I added all Layout Stuff into my App.vue and uses the routes like normal, why so complicated :)

```
    const routes = [

  { path: '/', name: 'home', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') },
  { path: '/users', name: 'users', component: () => import('pages/Users.vue') },
  { path: '/news', name: 'news', component: () => import('pages/News.vue') },
  { path: '*', component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue') },

];

export default routes;
```

and as nav links:

```
  <router-link
      v-for="route in $router.options.routes"
      :key="route.path"
      :to="route.path"
      >{{ route.name }}</router-link
    >
```

works as aspected.